# Posterior and prior exercise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm struggling with an exercise that's about posterior and prior distributions, and would really appreciate a push in the right direction.

Exercise: Assume that the number of requests for data that a computer server receives in an hour is Poisson$(\lambda)$ distributed, where $(\lambda)$ is the expected number
of requests per hour. Assume that during each of 6 hours of operation,
the number of requests were 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, and 3, respectively.

a) Using a prior that is proportional to $\frac{1}{(\lambda)}$ find the distribution for,
and plot using R, the posterior distribution for $(\lambda)$ given the data.

I don't really know where to start, apart from the fact that I know that Poisson and Gamma are conjugate priors.

Would anyone like to give me a hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your prior is proportional to $\frac{1}{\lambda} = \lambda^{-1}$. The density for a Gamma distribution is $\text{Gamma}(\lambda; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\lambda^{\alpha-1}\exp(-\beta\lambda)$. From this information you can express your prior as a Gamma distribution, which is a good start!